# Need to reuse old Tymon JWT token

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm using Laravel to feed some API to a simple app. I used Tymon JWT tokens to authorize CLIENTS (not users). So every client has a token that lets me discover what kind of app is calling the API.

Shame on me, I did a mistake and updated the old JWT random string and totally lost the old one. Is there a way to retrieve old random string or to let old tokens work with the new one?

I could update all the clients and make them work with new tokens, I don't have a huge installation count, but it doesn't sound like a good solution.